# Syntax errors running sqlite over ssh with eval

Tags: bash

I am receiving error message when I want to run this sqllite3 command in bash script . 
would appreciate any help.

```
DB_CMD="ssh -X node-11 \"cd ~/test/emane/gvine/node-10/ && sqlite3 -header -csv emane_data.db \"select * from rxfile;\" >>./out.csv\\"""
eval $DB_CMD

eval: line 56: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' eval: line 57: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sqlite3: Error: too many options:
```

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also, BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Passing commands over ssh already exposes them to one layer of `eval` processing. Adding a second one on top is taking something already error-prone and compounding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a fairly complex situation. Don't make it harder by trying to throw `eval` into the mix -- or at least let the shell itself do the work of building quoting that works.

```
# put a shell-quoted version of your sqlite command into sqlite_cmd_str
printf -v sqlite_cmd_str '%q ' sqlite3 -header -csv emane_data.db "select * from rxfile;"

# substitute that into remote_cmd_str
remote_command_str="cd ~/test/emane/gvine/node-10/ && ${sqlite_cmd_str} >>out.csv"

# ...now, run that remote command...
ssh -X node-11 "$remote_command_str"

# ...or, if you **really** want to use eval:
printf -v local_cmd_str '%q ' ssh -X node-11 "$remote_command_str"
eval "$local_cmd_str"
```

That said -- saving code in strings and `eval`'ing them is **not** a best practice. Instead, consider using a function for the local-evaluation part of this:

```
run_remote_sql() {
  local sqlite_cmd_str remote_cd_cmd_str remote_cmd_str
  local node_num=$1

  printf -v sqlite_cmd_str '%q ' \
    sqlite3 -header -csv emane_data.db "select * from rxfile;"
  printf -v remote_cd_cmd_str '%q ' \
    cd "test/emane/gvine/node-$1"
  remote_cmd_str="$remote_cd_cmd_str && $sqlite_cmd_str >>out.csv"
  ssh -X "node-$1" "$remote_cmd_str"
}
```

...to define a function which might be invoked as:

```
run_remote_sql 10
```

---

Or, doing the parameter-management on the remote end:

```
run_remote_sql() {
  printf -v extra_args '%q ' "$@"
  ssh -X node-"$1" "bash -s $extra_args" <<'EOF'
cd ~/test/emane/gvine/node-"$1"/ || exit
sqlite3 -header -csv emane_data.db "select * from rxfile;" >>./out.csv
EOF
}
```

...for, again...

```
run_remote_sql 10
```

---

Now, why all the `printf %q`? First, it means you don't need to do all the quoting yourself (as you may have noticed, correctly quoting for multiple nested evaluation levels is hard!). Second: Security reasons.

Think about what happens if your program gets run with an argument of `'$(rm -rf /)'` -- you don't ever want it to be possible for your script to run `cd ~/test/emane/gvine/node-$(rm -rf /)`; using `printf %q` to build eval-safe strings ensures that content is always safely escaped.

---

Next question: Why is it safe to put some things, like `>>out.csv`, **outside** of `printf %q`, as constants? Because:

- These pieces contain shell syntax, which `printf %q` would -- by safely escaping -- turn into data, making them no longer respected as a directive by the shell.
- The data components are constants. If `out.csv` were instead `$2.csv`, then we'd want to use `printf %q` to escape the `"$2"` part.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the command:  `./out.csv\"""`

Looks like it ha an extra quote `"` at the end, and if so, the interpreter thinks it is the beginning of a new (but unterminated) string.

Comment: That's true, but it's also not even close to the entirety of the problem.